# Collapsible category tree in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am building a small project in which I am trying to make a category filter in a form of a collapsible tree.The problem is the data I have in my db is like this .

```
["Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Cameras & Photography->","Any Department->Electronics->Car & Vehicle Electronics->","Any Department->Electronics->Computers & Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->GPS & Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Hi-Fi & Home Audio->","Any Department->Electronics->Hi-Fi & Home Audio->Home Theater->","Any Department->Electronics->Mobiles & Tablets->","Any Department->Electronics->Portable Media Players->","Any Department->Electronics->Telephones & Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Warranties->","Any Department->Electronics->Wearable Technology->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Blank Media->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Camera & Photo Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Car & Vehicle Electronics Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Computer Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->General Purpose Batteries & Battery Chargers->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Home Audio & Video Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Memory Cards->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Mobile Accessories->","Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->Navigation Accessories->"].
```

and i want the data to look like this :

```
let tree = {
  label: 'root',
  nodes: [
    {
      label: 'item1',
      nodes: [
        {
          label: 'item1.1'
        },
        {
          label: 'item1.2',
          nodes: [
            {
              label: 'item1.2.1'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      label: 'item2'  
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You literally have a table consisting of strings like this `"Any Department->Electronics->Accessories->"`? Are there any relationships set up?

Comment: no relationship just a string table